# Sending multiple tokens from approved multiple addresses on ERC1155

Tags: erc-1155

I'm new on ERC1155. I've checked that ERC1155 `transfer` function contains call data:
`safeTransferFrom(address from,address to,uint256 id,uint256 amount,bytes data)`. 
What is the main purpose of this `byte[] data`? 
I've tried to send other approved tokens in this single transaction but it's not work, here is my transaction: 
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x90251dcecd091b7439630cdf5560c1f0332d230ffb24ec1d383479d4c5aa468b 
And here is my separate transaction which transfers from approved address to another address: 
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x37ac25b95c3dd0f98438f6a8365d1db5424b22238c2409d7711ea41baa58acc4 
So, how can I transfer multiple tokens ERC1155 from multiple approved addresses by only one transaction, thanks for help so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the bytes[] data is that it is passed as an argument to the [onERC1155Received](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155#IERC1155Receiver-onERC1155Received-address-address-uint256-uint256-bytes-) function for contracts that inherit from [IERC1155Receiver](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155#IERC1155Receiver). It is up to the IERC1155Receiver-contract to handle this data, if they want.

You will have to deploy a new contract that these addresses must approve. In this contract, you can create a function that takes in arguments of the addresses that a) you want to move tokens from AND b) have approved the contract. Then you can loop through these addresses and transfer them to the destination you want, but restrict this function so that only the owner, you, of the contract can run it. Just an example but the only way I see to go around doing this in one transaction is through this separate contract. It will be even more complicated if the ERC1155 tokens are from a different collection.